# Using Graph API not able to get events for particular date using filter param

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

```
var authEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?";
var redirectUri = "http://localhost:8080";
var appId = "SomethingSomething";
var scopes = "openid profile User.Read Mail.Read Calendars.Read";
function getUserEvents(callback) {
  getAccessToken(function(accessToken) {
    if (accessToken) {
      // Create a Graph client
      var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
        authProvider: done => {
          // Just return the token
          done(null, accessToken);
        }
      });

      // Get the 10 newest events
      client
        .api("/me/events")
        .filter("startDateTime='2018-03-01'&endDateTime='2018-03-31'")
        .select("subject,start,end,createdDateTime")
        .orderby("createdDateTime DESC")
        .get((err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            callback(null, err);
          } else {
            callback(res.value);
          }
        });
    } else {
      var error = { responseText: "Could not retrieve access token" };
      callback(null, error);
    }
  });
}
```

**This is the request that my program sends out:**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=2018-07-15T01:00:00&$select=subject,start,end,createdDateTime&$orderby=createdDateTime%20DESC`

`400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: The request you pasted at the end is incorrect as there's no `displayName` property. However, please check the rest of your code as it's quite strange that you filter date and in the request you see filters for subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to filter the [`/events`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_events) endpoint using properties that don't exist in the [`event`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) object (`startDateTime` and `endDateTime`). You're also passing a `=` in the filter clause instead of `eq`.

The [`/calendarView`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview) endpoint does have `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` parameters, but these are query params unto themselves (not part of a filter clause). I suspect this is the operation you're actually looking for:

```
client
  .api("/me/calendarview")
  .query({
    startdatetime: "2018-03-01T00:00:00.0000000",
    enddatetime: "2018-03-31T23:00:00.0000000"
  })
  .select("subject,start,end,createdDateTime")
  .orderby("createdDateTime DESC")
  .get((err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      callback(null, err);
    } else {
      callback(res.value);
    }
  });
```

Comment: 'client.api('/me/events').filter("start/dateTime ge '2018-07-19T08:00'")`                             **I have changed the filter parameters now it works ** thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that will only show master events. Recurring event instances will _not_ be returned using `/events`.

Comment: Is this possible to get the selected appointment ( events ) data in outlook calendar. Because i need to display the selected calendar view data in calendar Add Ins .